# It there any tiled console/command prompt for Windows OS?

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin, mintty

I need to monitor 2-4 console windows at the same time. Now I'm using 4 cygwin mintty windows, each takes 1/4 of my whole desktop space. The problem is that they aren't tied together. And if I switch to some other window (eg., Fx or Eclipse etc) and then want to switch back I have to find all these 4 windows. It's a pain. So I'm looking for some enhanced command prompt manager similar to tiled *nix window manager. Tabs aren't suitable for me.
I've already found PowerCmd, but 1) it's not free, 2) overloaded with features (I need only mintty with tiles), 3) there are reviews which claim that it's quite buggy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some alternatives are.

- [**ConEmu**](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/)

  > ConEmu-Maximus5 is a Windows console emulator with tabs, which presents multiple consoles and simple GUI applications as one customizable GUI window with various features.

  [image]
- [**Console**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)

  > Console is a Windows console window enhancement. Console features
  >   include: multiple tabs, text editor-like text selection, different
  >   background types, alpha and color-key transparency, configurable font,
  >   different window styles

  [image]

Comment: They have only tabs - so you couldn't see all 4 consoles at the same time.

Comment: Ok, ConEmu has tiles now (actually, I believe it has had them for some time already) and I'm slightly switching from ConsoleZ to ConEmu. Reason: it supports back-history (ctrl+R) search, could mix tiles (eg: one is bash, another - windows cmd).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console), which also has tabs but lets you split the main window, so you can see multiple consoles at the same time:

[image]

this shows just tree panels, but you can have 4 and more as well.

Comment: Excellent! It also supports cygwin's bash.

Comment: I've changed my mind in favor of ConEmu. It has more features, and is less out-of-date than ConsoleZ.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why not just use any terminal and screen? Or tmux? Both have the benefit of being able to open it on another X desktop or console alltogether, including multiple views (perhaps just to keep it on your desktop but connect remotely via ssh from work and taking a peek without detaching the desktop client.

Edit, 5.4.2020

Actually, you could use 4NT to replace CMD (.EXE both). 4NT is enhanced version, there has also been 4DOS.EXE (while it replaced COMMAND.COM) and 4OS/2, used them all, and all could be configured ANSI, without loading ansi.sys though... Then, start-up commands should set environment variable, TERM to value ANSI. Maybe the command was: set TERM=ANSI, then call Cygwin from screen...

Comment: Because I work on Windows and do ssh to different Linux boxes.

Comment: BTW for Linux tmux is my favorite,

Comment: Matter of taste.But the docs is very inconsistent,hotkeys linked or described with similar category, or desc.Some work with panes, some windows.I once found an relative easy and consistent beginners guide that explain what pane and window mean consistently. I learned basics, even the messy way to see pane to specific size - if it lacked that, a very simple command combination could do that. It was to hard, to limiting. Even if I can't have same window in many panes or the otherway, cant I switch panes and select window you want by name or number? Why so complex? Screen seems more powerful.

Comment: St. Shadow - well, you could use Cygwin - FOSS Unix-like subsystem for Windows. Install at least xterm, openssh and screen. You can use the plain Cygwin console (doesn't need X server) our you can follow Cygwin site for guides and maybe installer including the X server (I recall it's name was like MingX). Launching the X server at :0.0, open terminal if one isn't, and try launch X application, like xterm. With or without X, Cygwin terminal runs screen fine, CMD nor PowerShell don't support even ANSI codes, but 4NT (CMD.EXE replacement) and likely Take Command can also deal with'em.